# QOpenglWidget black screen on transparency change

Tags: qt, opengl, opengl-3

I am using Qt5.4.2 on windows, and I am trying to implement a QOpenGLWidget inherited widget.
The window should be capable to render tranparently and solidly, which means the user should be able to switch between the two renderings in the program.

When I start the program with Depth_test, it works fine, also when i start the program with blending it works fine. BUT: when I change the transparency in execution, I got black window, when I switch back to depth_test! And when I switch back to blending It is normal again
So the problem happens just when I change the transparency to depth_test.

I tried the same thing with the older QGLWidget: Works flawless, so there is no black window.

```
if (/transparent or not/)
{

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


} else
{
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


}update();
```

Interesting also the following: When I enable GL_CULL_FACE :
 I got black window, but when I switch back to transparency, I got also half black window (diagonal separated).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
Finally I got the answer.
At the begining I should write:

`doneCurrent();
 makecurrent();`